# multipart identifier error with joins and cases

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have below query which joins and case condition. And i am getting multipart identifier error at "`ELSE TP1.ValidSupervisorID`". Below is the query.

```
SELECT
  distinct TP.PeopleKey,
  TP1.ValidSupervisorID
FROM tbl_People TP

LEFT JOIN (  select tbl_People.PeopleKey,
    CASE
        WHEN tbl_People.SupervisorID in (select PersonnelNbr from tbl_People) THEN tbl_People.SupervisorID
        ELSE ''
    END ValidSupervisorID
    FROM tbl_People 
    ) as TP1 on TP.PeopleKey = TP1.PeopleKey

LEFT JOIN (  select tbl_People.PeopleKey,
  CASE
    WHEN tbl_People.CareerCounselorID in (select PersonnelNbr from tbl_People) THEN tbl_People.CareerCounselorID
    WHEN tbl_People.CareerCounselorID=NULL OR tbl_People.CareerCounselorID='' THEN tbl_People.CareerCounselorID
    ELSE TP1.ValidSupervisorID
  END ValidCareerCounselorID
    FROM tbl_People 
    ) as TP2 on TP1.PeopleKey = TP2.PeopleKey
```

could some one please help?

Comment: `tbl_People.CareerCounselorID=NULL` won't work neither.

Answer (score 1):

You can't reference TP1 from within the second sub query; because until it finishes the join operation it doesn't know which row of TP1 it's joined to.

The easiest solution would be to return null,  and put the case statement in the outer query.

To be honest, I don't see what the TP2 is actually for? It has no effect on the outcome of the query as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access to TP1 inside LEFT JOIN, use [OUTER APPLY](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156) instead.